# Convert hexadecimal to decimal in java

Tags: java

I've been doing a program to convert Hexadecimal numbers into decimal numbers and back. I've been stuck with this problem all day. I have the following code:

```
    for (String element: list) {
        double number = 0;
        int i=0;
        while(i<element.length()) {
            char character = element.charAt(i);
            if (character=='A' | character== 'a') {
                int a= (int) (10*(Math.pow((element.length()-(i+1)), 16)));
                number= number+a;
            }
            else {
            if (character== 'B' | character =='b') {
                int a= (int) (11*(Math.pow((element.length()-(i+1)), 16)));
                number= number+a;
            }
            else {
            if (character== 'C' | character =='c') {
                int a= (int) (12*(Math.pow((element.length()-(i+1)), 16)));
                number= number+a;
            }
            else {
            if (character== 'D' | character =='d') {
                int a= (int) (13*(Math.pow((element.length()-(i+1)), 16)));
                number= number+a;
            }
            else {
            if (character== 'E' | character =='e') {
                int a= (int) (14*(Math.pow((element.length()-(i+1)), 16)));
                number= number+a;
            }
            else {
            if (character== 'F' | character =='f') {
                int a= (int) (15*(Math.pow((element.length()-(i+1)), 16)));
                number= number+a;
            }
            else {

            if (character =='1') {
                int a= (int) (1*(Math.pow((element.length()-(i+1)), 16)));
                number= number+a;
            }
            else {
            if (character =='2') {
                int a= (int) (2*(Math.pow((element.length()-(i+1)), 16)));
                number= number+a;
            }
            else {

            if (character =='3') {
                int a= (int) (3*(Math.pow((element.length()-(i+1)), 16)));
                number= number+a;
            }
            else {
            if (character =='4') {
                int a= (int) (4*(Math.pow((element.length()-(i+1)), 16)));
                number= number+a;
            }
            else {
            if (character =='5') {
                int a= (int) (5*(Math.pow((element.length()-(i+1)), 16)));
                number= number+a;
            }
            else {
            if (character =='6') {
                int a= (int) (6*(Math.pow((element.length()-(i+1)), 16)));
                number= number+a;
            }
            else {
            if (character =='7') {
                int a= (int) (7*(Math.pow((element.length()-(i+1)), 16)));
                number= number+a;
            }
            else {
            if (character =='8') {
                int a= (int) (8*(Math.pow((element.length()-(i+1)), 16)));
                number= number+a;
            }
            else {
            if (character=='9') {
                int a= (int) (9*(Math.pow((element.length()-(i+1)), 16)));
                number= number+a;
            }
            else {
            if (character =='0') {
                int a= (int) (0*(Math.pow((element.length()-(i+1)), 16)));
                number= number+a;
            }
        }}}}}}}}}}}}}}}
            i++;
            }
```

I know its quite big and dumb. The problem I'm facing is that when i run it and put a number like AAA it throws the value of A000A hexadecimal. Or if i put 123 it throws the value of 10002 in hexadecimal. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Start making it less "big and dumb" (your words). Use character.toUpperCase so you don't need to compare against both upper and lowercase version. Pull the `number= number+a;` out of *each* if statement and do it once below all if statements. Pull the `Math.pow((element.length()-(i+1)), 16))` our of *each* if statement and do it once below all if statements.

Comment: 2 things: learn what `else if` is, learn what `switch` is.

Comment: Thanks for the betterment of the code, I just re-wrote it with all the advice that you guys gave me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary problem is that you've flipped the order of the `Math.pow` arguments.

Instead of `34 hex = 3*16^1 + 4*16^0 = 52` you are doing `34 hex = 3*1^16 + 4*0^16 = 3` which obviously gives the wrong result.

Flip the order, e.g.:

```
        if (character=='A' | character== 'a') {
            int a= (int) (10*(Math.pow(16, (element.length()-(i+1)))));
            number= number+a;
        }
```

Comment: Oh my, thank a lot. Read on a random post how to use it and they gave me the wrong order aparently. Again, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is your task to make your own implementation or you just need a convertor?
If you need just convertor you can do this `Integer.parseInt("a",16)`

**Edited: general recommendation**
In order to make your code more readable I'd recommend to create private static map inside the class, like this:

```
    private static final Map<Character, Integer> dictionary = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    static {
        myMap.put("A", 10);
        myMap.put("B", 11);
        //other code
    }
```

So you would be able to get rid of code duplication:

```
   Integer multiplier = dictionary.get(Character.toUpperCase(character))
   if(multiplier == null){/* do something */}
   int a= (int) (multiplier*(Math.pow(16, (element.length()-(i+1)))));
   number= number+a;
```

Comment: I need to make my own version.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice, I'll try to implement it on my code so that it performs better. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your program using the String method toLowerCase() `element.toLowerCase()`, so you can delete the double validation. Also you can use the Integer methods to convert hex to decimal and viceversa:

`Integer.parseInt(yourString, 16);`

`Integer.parseToHex(yourString);`

Comment: Thanks for the tip in the toLowerCase part, I didnt think about it until you mentioned it. With the other advice, the concept of doing the conversion was to find a new way of doing the conversion without the inherited method and comparing the speed/data usage.